# How to make responsive select with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm making form for adding user and have two comboboxes and it work ok for pc, notebooks,.., but when i test for small devices and click on combobox it show me only part of text everything else is black

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Add user</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Type:  </label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select class="form-control"  id="user_type" name="user_type">
                            <option value="1">Admin</option>
                            <option value="2">Worker</option>
                            <option value="3">Client</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                        <input type="submit" name="btn-add" class="form-control" value="Add user">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qjnV.jpg)

Do you have any suggestion how can i make this to work on small devices?

Comment: its working fine in mobile view also.. [link](http://www.bootply.com/jK9x3CVPXl)

Comment: thx for reply, i also now check with firefox and it working fine, only when i check with chrome it's not working

Comment: in chrome also its working !